# Проблема с подключением блоков

Tags: twig

Решил сделать содержимое тега `<head>` в виде шаблонов, так как на каждой странице что-то есть, чего-то нет. Запихнул все возможное содержимое в отдельный файл примерно такого содержания:

```
{% block meta %}<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">{% endblock %}
{% block style %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">{% endblock %}
{% block jquery %}<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>{% endblock %}
{% block script %}<script src="js/script.js"></script>{% endblock %}
```

В нужный мне шаблон, в `<head>`, делаю необходимые мне вставки так: `{% block meta %}{% endblock %}` и т.д., но шаблон не хочет работать. Пробовал добавлять в начало файла путь к родителю, например `{% extends "../index.html" %}`, но безрезультатно. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил вопрос, думал решил :) В документации нашел, что можно передавать массив шаблонов (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html ), но насторожила строчка "The first template that exists will be used as a parent", то ли это? Главный вопрос остается в силе. Если просто удалить {% block %}{% endblock %} у каждого элемента и подключить через include, то все работает, а так нет.

Этот шаблон надо отдельно загружать. То есть, допустим, у меня 4 страницы, в каждой я просто подгружаю нужный мне html-шаблон, например, на index.php подгружаю шаблон index.html, который в свою очередь содержит подключенные через include различные узлы страницы. Я бы мог так же через include подрузить и шаблон тегов в <head>, но проблема, как я уже говорил, что на каждой странице разные теги, грубо говоря, на одной странице может подключаться jquery, на другой - нет. И мне хотелось бы, чтобы index.html как бы наследовал файл с шаблонами для тега <head>

Answer (score 0):

```
если я правильно понял то должно быт так:
{{ block('meta') }} - то есть в кавычке указываем название блока.
или же можно просто {{include '...'}} воспользоваться...
удачи!)
```

Comment: include вряд ли подойдет, так как на каждую страницу нужно подключать определенные блоки. А вот с синтаксисом     {{ block('meta') }} тоже не хочет работать. По ходу дела возник еще один вопрос:  блоки из файла с шаблонами используются сразу на нескольких страницах, как мне в extends указать эти страницы - через запятую, например,     {% extends "../index.html", "../about.html" %}  или каждый раз писать новый extends с новым именен файла?

Comment: к сожалению каждый раз будете писать..(((